# Variance from sampling from a collection of marbles

Tags: probability, variance, combinatorics

Suppose I have $N$ marbles, $k$ of which are black. Let $X$ be the number of black marbles obtained from randomly choosing $M$ ($\leq N$) marbles. What is the variance of $X$?

Obviously if $M=N$ then $X=k$. Otherwise I can only think of approaching the problem by trying to find a formula for $P(X=0),\,P(X=1),\dots$ but this appears to be somewhat combinatorial in nature and my combinatorics isn't up to scratch at the moment.

Comment: Please indicate whether this is homework or self-study. This is actually standard, introductory text-book material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a draw without replacement, $X$ follows a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), with $M,N$ and $k$ as parameters
Then, you can obtain the variance from this law.